# Android Firebase login invalid idToken

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to implement authentication with Firebase, but i'm currently facing some strange problems.

In my backend, i'm using this to verify token:

```js
async getUser(token: string) {
    const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
        idToken: token,
        audience: CLIENT_ID
    });

    const payload = ticket.getPayload();
    const userid = payload.sub;

    ...
}
```

When i send this token from `IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)`, everything works just fine.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        val response = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            response?.idpToken?.let {
                val loginRepo = LoginRepository(this)
                loginRepo.login(Login(it), {}, {})
            }
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

But when i send token from `currentUser`, `async getUser(token: string)` always throw a exception.

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
if (user != null) {
    user.getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener {
        if (it.isSuccessful) {
            val token = it.result?.token
            val loginRepo = LoginRepository(this)
            token?.let { loginRepo.login(Login(it), {
                ...
            }, {
                ...
            }) }
        }
    }
}
```

Exception thrown:

> Error: No pem found for envelope:
>   {"alg":"RS256","kid":"...","typ":"JWT"}

When using: `https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123` token retrieved from idpResponse works fine, but the other token retrieved from currentUser does not, returns:

> {
>       "error": "invalid_token",
>       "error_description": "Invalid Value" }

How can i get de idpToken from currentUser? Why does not idToken works?

Answer (score -1):

you may need to check the firebase documentation :

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getIdToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                // ...
            } else {
                // Handle error -> task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I already did it, my code is the same as yours, but in Kotlin.